# How to add optional module to IIS Web Application? (without direct reference)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications

We have a client-server PMS application, in which the server is a standard .NET Framework 4.5 web application hosted in IIS.

We need to implement an interface/connector that is only **optionally** present, and can connect the server to another, 3rd party software that communicates through HTTPS/TLS 1.2 calls. Our interface would need to behave towards this 3rd party software as a client (so it does not need to host any services).

We have the following problems:

- This interface should be optional, it might not get deployed with the server. It should be exclude-able from Publishing without breaking anything.
- Because of the TLS 1.2 requirement this interface project needs to be built with Framework 4.6.2, so since it's higher version we cannot add it to the references of the server (we do not want to change the server's Framework requirements).

So basically we would need to be able to create a server that upon startup looks for an optional module, and if it's present can load it and invoke its methods.

The only option I could think of this far is to create the interface as a WCF service, which would then basically act like a proxy. This way we wouldn't need to directly add it to the server's references, the Framework version also wouldn't cause a headache, and the optional deployment would be easy. (so our server would invoke this WCF service (interface) which would pass the call over to the 3rd party system)
...But it just doesn't feel right... feels like an overkill actually. And also the WCF Contracts' limitations (we would have complex return types) would also cause a headache...

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: i think because of the framework conflict, you are forced to a separate communication application - consider webapi, it deals with complex types more nicely than wcf in my experience

Comment: Well, that could work although doesn't seem to be much "better" than WCF, but at least instead of contracts we get json... Hm, will see which one wins, I hoped there is a more elegant way to do all this.

Comment: another option might me to invoke a communication .exe on the server - something like running those old cgi-bin stuff - but could become a security nightmare

Comment: optionally loading a module is easy and possible, the issue is the framework conflict, that constraint forces you out of the single application solution, i think